# C++ Build & Send DNS Packet

Tags: c++, c, sockets, dns

I'm working on a DNS resolver in C++, constructing the DNS header is giving me problems. From what I've been able to gather, the header can be constructed through a struct.

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned short id;

  unsigned char qr :1; // 0 query, 1 response
  unsigned char opcode :4; // 0 standard query
  unsigned char aa :1; // authoritive answer
  unsigned char tc :1; // truncated message
  unsigned char rd :1; // recursion desired

  unsigned char ra :1; // recursion available
  unsigned char z :3; // reserved
  unsigned char rcode :4;  // response code

  unsigned q_count :16; // number of question entries
  unsigned ans_count :16; // number of answer entries
  unsigned auth_count :16; // number of authority entries
  unsigned add_count :16; // number of resource entries
} HEADER;

typedef union {
  HEADER header;
  unsigned char packet_data[1024];
} DNS_PACKET;
```

I set the header values, place the header in DNS_PACKET, cast as (void *) and send the packet using sendto().

Viewing one of the sent packets in Wireshark shows that the bits are not being set in the correct locations. For example I set q_count to 1, but Wireshark displays the packet with 256 questions.

In all the documentation I've read, this appears to be a valid route to constructing a packet. Am I going about this incorrectly? Is there a better method to construct a packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you can use libnet to build the DNS packet. It will be much easier, never worry about the header's format.

**and you sure you have done  the hton() or htonl() ?**

Comment: I had forgot to use hton, looks like you've set me back on the right track. Thanks.