# C++ unsigned char syntax

Tags: c++

I was looking at setting up a DNS header packet and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441193/c-build-send-dns-packet) written online
in the code. what does this mean?

```
 unsigned char qr :1;
```

I figure it means that its an unsigned char of size one bit. I just want some clarification, I don't know how to search this and I can't find anything on it in the c++ documents.

Comment: Search for *bitfields*.

Comment: i deleted the c tag. It is in C++.

Comment: Actually, it is both C and C++.